# htaccess redirects not working on Apache server

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect **non-www** to **www** version of the website. I've redirected many sites but never had this problem. I have a typical WP installation on Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu) server.

I've placed the following code before `# BEGIN WordPress`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I also tried this with no results.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Everything I do, I get: FORBIDDEN - You don't have permission to access / on this server.

How to make this redirect to work? Is there something I should pay attention to on the server side?

Comment: wordpress is totally different , did you redirect wordpress websites like that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to modify httpd.conf?
[RedirectPermanent](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) is a good choice to replace .htaccess if not works.

example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xy.example.com
RedirectPermanent / http://abc.example.com/
# optionally add an AccessLog directive for
# logging the requests and do some statistics
</VirtualHost>
```